# What is "FIPS BoringSSL v1.4, FIPS SKC v2.1, and FIPS SCrypto v2.5" on samsung phone(S10+)? What are these?

Tags: android, openssl, samsung-mobile, android-developer-api, boringssl

for some reason I found out that these disappeared on my phone's About phone > Software Information under security software information id. I had these before as shown on the image I attached, it was when I had my phone running on android 3.1.

My s10 plus have been updated to One ui 4.1 with security patch level Mar-2023.

My sister's Galaxy A51 had these and her phone is running on the latest android version also. I also googled if other s10 phones have these as of now and found out that they still had these and they are running on latest version of one ui .

Is this a sign that my phone was compromised? How do I get these back? If these are still present on my phone and they just don't show on software information, How do I know if I really still have these?

[Screenshot of S10 plus software information running on one ui 3.1 android 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHxUC.jpg)

I tried updating the firmware to latest version using smart switch and it did nothing. How do I get these back?